# How to code Tensor Networks?

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, tensor-network

I'm interested in learning tensor networks, I've been reading some introductory articles about this. The problem is that these articles mostly discuss the theoretical definitions for tensor networks such as MPS, PEPS, etc.. The problem is that discussions regarding how to program these for obtaining ground states in condensed matter physics are rather concise. Even for a simple wave function I'm lost on how to calculate the SVD (the index juggling confuses me a bit). I'm also interested in learning MERA and TEBD, but again, the discussions are mainly theoretical.

Are there any articles or maybe blogs discussing implementations of Tensor networks in code? maybe in python so these codes are easily accesible?
What would be a good way to learn how to program this algorithms?

Comment: If you know c++, http://itensor.org/. This is mostly geared towards DMRG but it also provides a library for general tensor operations, and the "tutorials" on SVD and tensor diagrams are pretty general.

Comment: (_originally an answer which I've now deleted since I'm really not able to speak to the substance of these libraries_) I might try [`pyUni10`](http://uni10-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#preparing-your-system) if you code in Python 2. They've got some tutorials up there, and there's [a paper (on the original C++ library) by Kao et al. 2015](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/640/1/012040/pdf).

Alternatively [`tncontract`](https://github.com/andrewdarmawan/tncontract) or maybe [`ncon`](https://github.com/mhauru/ncon)?

Answer (score 4):

An online platform where you can learn about tensor networks, their definitions, index juggling, Python/Matlab/Julia codes describing MERA, TRG, TNR, Exact Diagonalization is -- https://www.tensors.net/. 
A very useful routine (which the above website uses for handling and contracting indices is known as "NCON" mentioned in https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0939

You must be patient and follow the missing links in your understanding using review articles such as -- https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164